# SQL Server Linked Server during Development

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, linked-server

I am creating a SQL Server database (call it a) on my development system (call it A), which needs data from another production-database-server (b, on Server B).

So, I set up the other server as a linked server. No problem so far.

When finished that database (a) should run on server B, so there would be no more need for a linked server.

But in my STPs I got a lot of B.b.dbo.tablename which would need to be altered to simply b.dbo.tablename...

I want to avoid this.

Any idea how I can do this.

Would it be a severe performance hit, if I simply set up a Linked Server on B pointing to itself (if that is possible)...?

Hope I could make sense!

Thank you,
Reinhard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the linked server referring to itself.

However, an easier way might be use a [synonym](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx) that hides the 4 part name.

```
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.myLocaltable FOR LinekdServer.dbname.dbo.myLocaltable
```

or

```
CREATE SYNONYM myLocaltable FOR LinekdServer.dbname.dbo.myLocaltable
```

This way, all references to myLocaltable will be, er, local.